# Can you recharge MonCash (Haiti mobile money app) from the US?

Tags: usa, money, mobile-apps, haiti

Haitian mobile operator Digicel has a mobile money transfer app called [MonCash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.useboom.htwallet&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true). It seems to be pretty effective for transferring money in-country, and is even accepted by some significant vendors. But there is no in-app way to add/send money to a MonCash account while in the US.

Is there some work-around that would allow you to do this?

[Not sure if this is the right community for this question. If there is a better community for it, please migrate the question.]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not app support, contact the developer

Comment: This was already mentioned in a recent review of the app, complete with a response from the app developer (which said nothing useful, of course).

Comment: This might possibly be on topic at [money.se]. But if your desire is to send money to someone in Haiti, you may want to ask a more general question about how to do that task, rather than making it specific to this app. You also should be aware of potential scams and send money only to people you actually know and only after verifying that the person is who you think it is.